# What does this means in css font: 20vmin/1 FontNameBold;?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have a project and they give me a starting site with the following css:

```
h1 {
  //more styles...
  font: 20vmin/1 FontNameBold;
  
}
```

This is the first time I encounter something such as `font: 20vmin/1 FontNameBold;`, what is this supposed to do in css?

Also in the specifications sheets they say:

> Typography
>
> Titles 21/48 FontNameBold
>
> Body 16/48 FontNameBold

So yeah I understand one is for the titles and the other for the body but what is 21/48 actually all about? This is the first time I find an especification like this, pretty confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's shorthand notation for: `font-size` / `line-height` `font-family`

**Viewport Sized Typography:**

`vmin` is a value introduced with CSS3 that will size things relative to your viewport. [Chris Coyier does a fantastic job of explaining viewport sized typography on CSS Tricks.](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

In your example, setting something to `20vmin` will set that font size to `20vw` or `20vh`, whichever is smaller. If the smallest of your users viewport sizes (`vh` or `vw`) is 40cm, setting a font-size of 20vmin will divided by that value (40) by 20% to give you a font-size of 8cm.

The whole idea behind this is that if the user re-sizes their viewport, your font-size will adjust accordingly for a more responsive user experience.

**The line-height property:**

`line-height` simply defines the amount of space above and below inline elements (such as text in a `<p>` tag. [Chris Coyier does a fantastic job of explaining the line-height property on CSS Tricks.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/)